# VLC Compile. Add Button and play video

Tags: android, video, compilation, apk, vlc

Have the source code VLC.
Compiled under android.
Added activity.
It has three buttons.
at the touch of a button should switch the channel stream , video from sd card or video from internet.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.b1:

      break;
    case R.id.b2:

        break;
    case R.id.b3:
    Context context = this;
    VideoPlayerActivity.start(context, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xjw2PtKjJE",
                         null, false, false);                           
        break;
}
```

All compiled. By clicking the button, a player, but the video does not start to play. 
Blank screen and the player does not see the video.
The same problem with the video playback from the card.
Tell me how to handle the press of a button.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of VideoPlayerActivity.start

```
VLCCallbackTask task = new VLCCallbackTask(MainActivity.this)
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AudioServiceController c = AudioServiceController.getInstance();
        c.append("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xjw2PtKjJE");
    }
};
task.execute();
```